# Typescript Import/Export for front-end and back-end

Tags: typescript, frontend, backend

I have a typescript module that contain multiple classes in multiple `.ts` file. And I need to use import/export to use the class within another class. The problem I faced is the export/import method between front-end and back-end is different.

Front-End:

```
import OtherClass from "./OtherClass";
export default class ClassName {
    ...
}
```

Back-end:

```
const OtherClass = require("./OtherClass");
class ClassName {
    ...
}
module.exports = ClassName;
```

I would like to know how could I write/export/configure the code such that the typescript module can be used by both front-end and back-end?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use "normal" imports in both cases and configure typescript to compile to whatever format the project needs (you can have multiple tsconfigs)

Comment: Thanks @AlekseyL., just find that I can use `tsc --module commonjs` to build the backend code

Comment: Next I need to find out the way to make a `package.json` so both frontend and backend can use (with the npm install option)